# How to store color and style tags of products in a variable in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am setting up a new section in product page that show related products of selected product, i need only match color and style tags of selected product with related product of same brand, how can i achieve it?

Comment: how your tags are added for products, like color_brown? or just brown ?

Also do you use color names in product options, maybe it is possible to grab it from there ?

Answer (score 1):

1. ADD color, style or any tags in product tags.
2. Loop through related products
3. Use if else statement to filter your products based on tags(style and color in your case).

   {% if product.tags contains 'color' or 'style' %}

   {% endif %}